# Google Recaptcha v3 from browser console

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have integrated v3 Recaptcha on our customer feedback form. On the Submit button, I pass the captcha token along with feedback text and optional email to a backend API to validate. This works fine.

But, I could trigger the API via browser console of the same page in a for loop like below and the response score for the triggers are 0.9. How do I prevent this? Is it a valid use case for captcha?

```
function createreq() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "API_URL_HERE", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    let param = {
        comment: "from browser console with google recaptcha",
        useremail: "test@gmail.com",
        language: "English",
        gCaptchaResponse: window.grecaptcha.getResponse()
    };
    xhttp.send(jsonToQueryString(param));
}

function jsonToQueryString(json) {
    return '' +
        Object.keys(json).map(function (key) {
            return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' +
                encodeURIComponent(json[key]);
        }).join('&');
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    window.grecaptcha.execute().then(function () {
        createreq();
    });
}
```